# INNER JOIN on One Table but different Parameter

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get different values on rows of one table, and I can't think of how to that.

Lets say for example:

```
table1
id  |  name  |  empCode | insCode 
 1    John   |   E101   |   I101


table2
id  |  code    | name | role
 1  |   E101   | Mich |   2
 2  |   I101   | Bran |   3
```

table1 has `reference id` of table2, and `empCode` and `insCode` in table1 dependes on `code` and `role` in table2.

What I want is like this:

```
id | code  |  name  | empCode | insCode | role | 
 1 |  ?    |  John  |  E101   |  I101   |  ?   |
```

I honestly don't know if its possible to retrieve multiple rows in same table in one `select` query.
If its not, what other possible solutions can I go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your table design but you can get as your expected with below query:

```
select 
result1.id, 
result1.code,
result1.name, 
result1.empCode, 
result1.insCode, 
result1.role as role_of_empCode,
result2.role as role_of_insCode
from (
  SELECT tbl1.id, 
  tbl2.code,
  tbl1.name, 
  tbl1.empCode, 
  tbl1.insCode, 
  tbl2.role
  FROM `table2` tbl2
  INNER JOIN `table1` tbl1 
  on tbl2.code = tbl1.empCode
) as result1, 
`table2` result2
where result1.insCode = result2.code
ORDER BY result1.id;
```

[You can check in this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97f08bb/28)!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Upon checking the link you provided it seems this the exact possible answer I am looking for. Marked as an answer. Really appreciate your help and time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:
SELECT a.*, b.role FROM
table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id=b.id

Also you may want to consider removing empcode and inscode from table 2 since its being redundant in table 1 OR vice versa depending on what your objectives are.

Comment: I know something `inner join` but the problem is my `table` design, so it wont work the way I wanted. So, in that case, what I did was create another query for retrieving another `row` and it works but now, instead one query, it goes to two. I think that's how it will be. Thanks for your posted answer anyway.